# jquery adding path in background url

Tags: jquery

I have a structure like this:

```
<div class="size" style="background: url(image1.jpg) no-repeat;">
```

So, in each div like described just above, i would like to add '480/' before the image name and like this:

```
<div class="size" style="background: url(480/image1.jpg) no-repeat;">
```

Any Jquery or javascript idea?

Comment: why can't you modify the original source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't modify the source, try

```
$('div.size[style]').css('background-image', function (i, background) {
    return background.replace(/(.*)\/(.*)/, '$1/480/$2')
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/39bbwg88/)

Comment: Thank you Arun.
Please 2 questions:
1) Can you tll me what is the "i" argument in the function?
2) For the first div, it works but for the next ones there is 2 times 480/ like this:

url(480/480/image1.jpg)

Many thanks for your support.

Comment: @eric yes, what is it

Comment: It was my mistake for the second question.

Comment: both of the solutions wrks perfectly.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="size" style="background: url(image1.jpg) no-repeat;">
<div class="size" style="background: url(image2.jpg) no-repeat;">
<div class="size" style="background: url(image3.jpg) no-repeat;">

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.size').each(function() {
        var oldUrl = $(this).css("background-image");       
        oldUrl = oldUrl.split("/");
       var last_url = oldUrl.pop();
        var first_url = oldUrl.join('/')
        last_url = "/480/"+last_url;            
        var newUrl = first_url+last_url;    
        $(this).css("background", newUrl);
    });
})

</script>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/39bbwg88/5/